# Not adding 2 numbers correctly in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, drop-down-menu

i have a drop down list in my html with values show here,

```
<select id="thedropdown">
<option value="1">test1</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
<option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

And my javascript:

```
function myFunction()
{
var a = document.getElementById("thedropdown");
var b = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;

var y=b;
var x=y+2;
var demoP=document.getElementById("demo")
demoP.innerHTML= x;
}
```

However the answer when i click the button makes it 22 when it should be 4. you can see my problem. Cheers for help in advance

Comment: Probably because b is a string, and thence y, and thence you are converting the number 2 to a string and tacking it on the end of the first "2" string

Comment: Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/L3zbc/ uses parseInt()

Comment: check out `Javascript unary + operator` `x = +y + 2;`

Answer (score 6):

Right now your code concatenates strings. You need to [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) (or [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) or [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Negation.29)) the values before adding.

When using `parseInt()` make sure to [always specify the second argument (the radix)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters):

```
b = parseInt(a.options[a.selectedIndex].value, 10);
```

Comment: so do i have to create a new var for that like var c = parseInt(b)?

Comment: That would work, as would `b = parseInt(b)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use unary `+` to convert numeric string to a number:

```
var y=+b;
```

or

```
var x=+y+b;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are concatenating a string instead of adding numbers:

```
var x=y+2;
```

Try that:

```
var x=parseInt(y)+2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your values with parseInt function:

```
    var y = parseInt(b, 10) + 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If one of the operands is a string , `+` operator performs concatenation.

this will work

```
function myFunction()
{
  var a = document.getElementById("thedropdown");
  var b = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;

  var y=b;
  var x= parseInt(y) + 2;
  var demoP=document.getElementById("demo")
  demoP.innerHTML= x;
}
```

Note `var x= parseInt(y) + 2;`